# Mongodb database is not created

Tags: java, mongodb

I am creating  mongodb database and trying to insert records in it but problem is that database is not created
        My database name is "myMongoDB" and collection name is chanel when i run it,it gives 
    error and with BUILD SUCCESSFUL

```
    package databaseconnection;

    import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
    import com.mongodb.DB;
    import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
    import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;

    public class InsertDriver {

        public static void main(String args[])throws UnknownHostException
        {
            DB db=(new MongoClient("localhost",8080)).getDB("myMongoDB");
            DBCollection dbcollection=db.getCollection("chanel");
            BasicDBObject basicDBObject=new BasicDBObject();
            basicDBObject.put("name", "dhiraj");
            basicDBObject.put("subscription", 4100);
            dbcollection.insert(basicDBObject);

        }
    }


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.ReadPreference.primary()Lcom/mongodb/ReadPreference;
    at com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions$Builder.<init>(MongoClientOptions.java:52)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:128)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:117)
    at databaseconnection.InsertDriver.main(InsertDriver.java:21)
```

Comment: is mongodb path corrrect?

Comment: @vedat which path you are talking about? i have just added the required jar file to project

Comment: is 8080 correct port? you couldn't connect the database. so I think mongodb port may be wrong. Did you change mongodb port? Does mongodb run on 8080 or 27017?

Comment: @vedat yes my localhost port is 8080.actually database is not created after running program

Comment: @vedat  i tried with 27017 the default port of mongodb but it wont work in program

Comment: did you run mongod instance? because everything looks ok. there are connection problem. I haven't any java environment, I can't try now, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I want to clear, **Databases are created in MongoDB when you insert some data in any collection of that database.**

First of all, check MongoDB is running on your machine (*By default it will run on port 27017*)?

Try to insert some sample data from mongo shell.

sample commands:

```
use testDB
db.testCollection.insert({"name":"dev"});
```

It will inset this data in `testCollection` of `testDB` database. You can find it using :

```
db.testCollection.find()
```

If all this working fine. Then proceed with java driver.

**You code looks good besides that 8080 port (I am assuming you manually changed the port from 27017 to 8080) and make sure MongoDB is running.**

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you mix several different versions of java mongodb client library.

If you take a look at this version of ReadPreference for instance http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/2.7.3/com/mongodb/ReadPreference.java you'll see that there is no "primary" method there. But in different version it's there: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/2.9.1/com/mongodb/ReadPreference.java#ReadPreference.primary%28%29

Can you please list all jars from your classpath for more detailed help. It could be that classes from old mongodb client were added into some other jar.

Comment: list of jars --->1)mongo.jar  2)mongo-java-driver-2.11.3.jar

Comment: Why do you need mongo.jar ?

Comment: @Dhiraj, can you try to remove it from classpath?

Comment: now code is working with defalult port after uninstalled and then re-installing mongodb

Comment: @Dhiray, is your code finally working with both mongo.jar and mongo-java-driver-2.11.3.jar in classpath?

Comment: i removed mongo.jar from classpath and now my classpath having only mongo-java-driver-2.11.3.jar

Comment: @Dhiraj, I think this was your issue, I have strong feeling that you didn't need to reinstall MongoDB. It was enough to leave only one jar of these two. If you could try to return them both in the same order they were before we could check it. But I don't think you have enough motivation for that. In general it could be useful for others struggling with same problem to have evidence what is minimal change fixing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i dont know what was wrong with my previous code but i uninstalled the
mongodb completly and then reinstalled it and tried following code and it worked fine for me .

```
    package mongod;

    import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
    import com.mongodb.MongoException;
    import com.mongodb.WriteConcern;
    import com.mongodb.DB;
    import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
    import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
    import com.mongodb.DBObject;
    import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
    import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;
    import java.util.List;

    public class Mongod {
        //private static Object mongo;

        Mongod mongo;

        public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
            MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);

            DB db = mongoClient.getDB("testDB1");
            DBCollection dbcollection=db.getCollection("testCollection");
            BasicDBObject basicDBObject=new BasicDBObject();
            basicDBObject.put("name", "dhiraj");
            basicDBObject.put("subscription", 4100);
            dbcollection.insert(basicDBObject);
            //boolean auth = db.authenticate("admin", "admin123".toCharArray());   
            //System.out.println(auth);
            List<String> dbs = mongoClient.getDatabaseNames();

            for (String dbss : dbs) {
                System.out.println(dbss);
            }

        }

    }
```